# aws cloudformation WAF geo location condition

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, web-application-firewall

Trying to create a cloud formation template to configure WAF with geo location condition. Couldnt find the right template yet. Any pointers would be appreciated.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/web-acl-geo-conditions.html

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: I am not sure what I am missing after I went through the link you referred. Is there additional details that I am supposed to add?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the actual answer (as of this writing, July 2018) is that you cannot create geo match sets directly in CloudFormation. You can create them via the CLI or SDK, then reference them in the `DataId` field of a WAFRule's `Predicates` property.

---

Creating a GeoMatchSet with one constraint via CLI:

```
aws waf-regional get-change-token
aws waf-regional create-geo-match-set --name my-geo-set --change-token <token>
aws waf-regional get-change-token
aws waf-regional update-geo-match-set --change-token <new_token> --geo-match-set-id <id> --updates '[ { "Action": "INSERT", "GeoMatchConstraint": { "Type": "Country", "Value": "US" } } ]'
```

Now reference that GeoMatchSet id in the CloudFormation:

```
    "WebAclGeoRule": {
      "Type": "AWS::WAFRegional::Rule",
      "Properties": {
        ...
        "Predicates": [
          {
            "DataId": "00000000-1111-2222-3333-123412341234" // id from create-geo-match-set
            "Negated": false,
            "Type": "GeoMatch"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

Comment: A shame they don't support this! Thank you for this example

Answer (score 1):

There is no documentation for it, but it is possible to create the Geo Match in serverless/cloudformation.

Used the following in serverless:

```
Resources:
  Geos:
    Type: "AWS::WAFRegional::GeoMatchSet"
    Properties:
      Name: geo
      GeoMatchConstraints:
      - Type: "Country"
        Value: "IE"
```

Which translated to the following in cloudformation:

```
"Geos": {
  "Type": "AWS::WAFRegional::GeoMatchSet",
  "Properties": {
    "Name": "geo",
    "GeoMatchConstraints": [
      {
        "Type": "Country",
        "Value": "IE"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

That can then be referenced when creating a rule:

(serverless) :

```
Resources:
  MyRule:
    Type: "AWS::WAFRegional::Rule"
    Properties:
      Name: waf
      Predicates:
      - DataId:
          Ref: "Geos"
        Negated: false
        Type: "GeoMatch"
```

(cloudformation) :

```
"MyRule": {
  "Type": "AWS::WAFRegional::Rule",
  "Properties": {
    "Name": "waf",
    "Predicates": [
      {
        "DataId": {
          "Ref": "Geos"
        },
        "Negated": false,
        "Type": "GeoMatch"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that your question is too vague to solicit a helpful response. The [CloudFormation User Guide (pdf)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-ug.pdf) defines **many** different WAF / CloudFront / R53 resources that will perform various forms of geo match / geo blocking capabilities. The link you provide seems a subset of Web Access Control Lists (Web ACL) - see AWS::WAF::WebACL on page 2540.

I suggest you have a look and if you are still stuck, actually describe what it is you are trying to achieve.

Note that the term you used: "geo location condition" doesn't directly relate to an AWS capability that I'm aware of.

Finally, if you are referring to https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/10/aws-waf-now-supports-geographic-match/, then the latest Cloudformation User Guide doesn't seem to have been updated yet to reflect this.

Comment: The PDF link is dead.

Comment: Try this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/Welcome.html